# How to level up super fast in The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How do I level up really fast In Skyrim because I keep dying over and over again

Comment: [Related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/314879/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-increase-my-sneaking-level-early-on/314883#314883)

Comment: Have you tried changing the game's difficulty to make it easier?

Comment: This question needs more detail to be answered. What skill are you trying to level up?

Answer (score 4):

You're solving the wrong problem.

Skyrim is an open sandbox that tries to guide you with danger. If you are dying "over and over again", it means you wandered into an area that you should not be at.

This actually means something as simple as going off roads, because you'll start meeting sabretooth tigers and bears.

In a normal game, the normal progress is escaping from Helgen, going to Riverwood, and then proceeding to Whiterun, possibly joining The Companions. Almost nothing in that sequence should be killing you over and over in a normal difficulty game.

Once you progress the main story enough to get the famous "Fus-Ro-Dah", you have the ability to knock over even giants and mammoths, so the only thing that would prevent escape are dragons. Those you can literally run away from, and can't chase you indoors.

As to the actual question, even if you level up a lot, it still doesn't stop you from dying "over and over". Very little in your skills prolong your survivability. Your survivability is primarily from gear. The correct potion, enchantment, equipment, and even shouts (see Fus-Ro-Dah above) will all swing a fight in your favor more than simply "levelling up".

Comment: If you travel from Helgen to the standing stones and from there to Riverwood, wolves will appear that can kill you if you are on Legendary difficulty and are pretty hard to escape or outrun. Of course, playing on Legendary is a choice :).

Answer (score 2):

"Levelling up" in Skyrim is divided into two aspects: gaining experience, and unlocking skills.

Gaining experience is done primarily through practicing your skills - combat with weapons, bows, shields, casting spells, brewing potions, blacksmithing, sneaking, etc. Depending on which route you take, determines which skills you can unlock.

There are several ways that you can level up these skills, and accrue "experience" to level up your stats, easily, or quickly. Such as [sneaking backwards behind a stationary guard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/314879/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-increase-my-sneaking-level-early-on/314883#314883), or doing the ol' [brew a buff potion, enchant a pair of brewing gloves, brew a potion with your new gloves, then sell 'em all to the highest bidder](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-11-16-skyrim-crafting-skills-how-to-max-enchanting-alchemy-and-smithing).

Since Skyrim is a sandbox game, there are no "events" that allow you to level up. you can only level up through grinding.